# With drf-yasg, how to use statics schemas and manage custom permissions?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, documentation, django-rest-viewsets, drf-yasg

I am a little confused how to develop the documentation using the drf-yasg library. So I would like to ask exactly:

1. How can I use a **static** `swagger.json` file created by [swagger editor online](https://editor.swagger.io/) with **drf-yasg**?
   (There are endpoints in my project that don't have serializers and models, so i created the schema manually!)
2. My project use a permissions control with custom management. Is there any way to manage the endpoints urls in the schema if the user is not allowed permission to view specific endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

- `drf-yasg` creates the swagger.json file by crawling your `django-rest-framework` application. You cannot use it to merge an existing `swagger.json` file.
- You can specify permissions using `permission_classes=(permissions.AllowAny,),`. See [related](https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg/issues/58).